# updating a specific row from a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table that is being displayed on the user screen. When the user clicks on edit, I want him to be able to click the parameters of that specific row and to update a single parameter (e.g., name); then, the other parameters (e.g., email, password, and address) should remain the same.

```
name    email           password    address     action
user    user@gmail.com  user        u.address   edit
```

The code used for the edit link is:

```
echo"<td class='center'><a class='btn btn-info' href=\"admin_edit_user.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white'></i>Edit</a></td>";
```

Code on `admin_edit_user.php` page:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="admin_update_user.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" name="name" value="" type="text">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" name="email" value="" type="text">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" name="password" value="" type="text">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" name="address" value="" type="text">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="submit">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit" name="submit">
            </div>  
    </div>                          
</form>
```

After this form the user gets redirected to `admin_update_user.php` page

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
   $id = $_GET['id'];


    $query="SELECT * FROM user";
    $result=  mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $name_data=$row['name'];
            $name_email=$row['email'];
            $name_password=$row['password'];
            $name_address=$row['address'];
        }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            $address=$_POST['address'];

            if(empty($name))
                {
                    //if the value is empty its going to set it equal to the database value
                    $name=$name_data;
                }
            else 
                $name=$name;

            if(empty($email))
                {
                    $email=$name_email;
                }
            else 
                $email=$email;

            if(empty($password))
                {

                    $password=$name_password;
                }
            else 
                $password=$password;

            if(empty($address))
                {
                    $address=$name_address;
                }
            else 
                $address=$address;

        }
//0: demo.name  (value given for name)
//demo@gmail.com (value given for email)
//demo (value given forpassword)
//demo
//demo.address (value given for address)

        $sql = "UPDATE user SET name='".$name."',email='".$email."',password='".$password."',address='".$address."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";

        echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";


        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
        header("Location: admin_user_list.php");
        exit;
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

I am getting an error in update query. I would be highly obliged if someone could help.

P.S @ FortMauris here is the edited part that you wished to see.

```
   $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);

   $query="SELECT * FROM user";
   $result=  mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    //get the value from database
    while ($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $name_data=$row['name'];
        $name_email=$row['email'];
        $name_password=$row['password'];
        $name_address=$row['address'];

    }

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];

   if(empty($name))
    {
        //if the value is empty its going to set it equal to the database value
        $name=$name_data;
    }


    if(empty($email))
    {
        $email=$name_email;
    }

        if ($password == '')
    {

        $password=$name_password;
    }

    if(empty($address))
    {
        $address=$name_address;
    }

}

echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";

 $sql = "UPDATE user SET name='".$name."',email='".$email."',password='".$password."',address='".$address."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";


    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
mysqli_close($con);
//header("Location: admin_user_list.php");
exit;
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: what error you are you getting?

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: @sgt mysql_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: @NaincyGupta mysql_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On both pages add this line at the top `session_start();`
- Than on the `admin_edit_user` Add this line `$_SESSION['id']=$_GET['id'];`
- Than on `admin_update_user.php` add this line `$id=$_SESSION['id']`;
- Than on the same file this file `admin_update_user.php` you have this line `$id=$_GET['id']`; remove it.

  `$sql = "UPDATE user SET name='".$name."',email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email)."',password='".$password."',address='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$address)."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";`

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have reserved keyword in query try to change your query to and you are mixing mysql and mysqli.

remove this line `echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";`

```
$sql = "UPDATE `user` SET `name`='".$name."',`email`='".$email."',`password`='".$password."',`address`='".$address."' WHERE `id` =".$id;

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: admin_user_list.php");
exit;
```

if it dosn't work then print your query and try to run it manually in phpmyadmin or mysql;

Comment: i am getting a syntax error but i am not able to understand what went wrong

Comment: Here is the complete error message Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: it's correct and don't think it will create any issue

Comment: @Ram Sharma it is not showing any error now but it is not updating the values

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET name='".$name."',email='".$email."',password='".$password."',address='".$address."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";
```

Instead of this, try using this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET name = '$name', email = '$email', password = '$password', address = '$address' WHERE id = $id";
```

It is much cleaner and will solve lots of query issues.

**EDIT:**

The issue is probably with 1 of your variables having `'` or `"`.

when you put it in, it becomes something like this:

```
$sam = "Sam'";
$sql = "  UPDATE user SET name = 'sam''  ";
```

It detects an additional inverted comma and therefore returns an error.

Comment: okay sam, try echoing all the variables ($name, $email etc) and see if theres any field with problem. I think the problem is going to lie with Address, most probably having an inverted comma in one of these variable. try to escape it or remove it completely.

Comment: i tried your solution but still it is not giving the desired result

Comment: here is the output  0: UPDATE user SET name='',email='',password='',address='' WHERE id =''

Comment: Ahh i see. Try this. For your PHP codes, remove away all else statements that is checking if the variables are empty or not. Secondly, instead of using "if(empty($password))", use "if ($password == '')". empty() is used to check if a variable is declared or not but it's not used to check for '' or null.

Comment: if i delete my else statement won't it disturb my code as the else part is assigning new values to the parameter. i wish to assign the parameters if they are entered by the user or else they should retain their old value

Comment: it will not affect as you have already assigned it like this "$name = $_POST['name'];". The if statement will only runs if it satisfies the statement, which in this case has to be '' or null. If it contains something ('sam') then the if statement will not run and your else statement will be irrelevant because it is not doing anything.

Comment: i removed all the else statements and changed the password part also, but it is still not updating the data and after echo the update query i still got the same output that i got in the previous statement

Comment: Can you update your new codes to your thread again? I want to take a look again.